# Travis CI Android Play Services Error

Tags: android, travis-ci

I'm getting this error in travis when trying to build my android app.

```
 > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.jar
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.jar
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.jar
         file:/usr/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.pom
         file:/usr/local/android-
sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.jar
```

Here is the .travis.yml file:

```
language: android
    android:
      components:
        - tools
        - build-tools-23.0.3
        - android-23
        - extra-google-google_play_services
        - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
        - extra-android-m2repository
```

Here is the build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

It seems like travis should be able to find the play services dependency.
What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:
      components:
        - tools
        - build-tools-23.0.3
        - android-23
        - extra-google-m2repository # Gradle uses this component to find GPS
        - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23
        - extra-android-m2repository
```